# highlighting according to column and save as xlsx using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to add some highlighting based off a value in a column and save a file as an .xlsx... I can not seem to get the syntax correct though.  Thank you :)

```
' Highlight classifications
 For iRow = 2 To rData.Rows.Count 'Start at line #2 to ignore the header row
 Set rw = rData.Rows(iRow)

  If rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "VUS" Then
 rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6    'Yellow
ElseIf rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "not provided" Then _
 rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 21    'Purple
ElseIf rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic" Then _
 rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 9    ' Dark Red
End If
Next iRow
End If

' Create new workbooks based on name
 Dim sSave As String
 Dim sFN As String
 Dim Directory As String
 Beep
 sSave = MsgBox("The data has been formatted and classified. Do you want to save the workbook now?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)
If sSave = vbYes Then
Matrix 'Call the matrix routine
    sFN = [A1] & "_hg19annovar.xlsx"
    Directory = "N:\Torrent\Setup\Clinical\"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Directory & sFN, FileFormat:=51
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.Quit
    If sFN = "False" Then Exit Sub
Else
    MsgBox "This workbook has not yet been saved!", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this the bit that is giving errors?

```
  If rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "VUS" Then
     rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6    'Yellow
  If rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "not provided" Then _
     rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 21    'Purple
  If rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic" Then _
     rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 9    ' Dark Red
End If
```

It should be:

```
  If rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "VUS" Then
     rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 6    'Yellow
  ElseIf rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "not provided" Then _
     rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 21    'Purple
  ElseIf rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).Value = "likely pathogenic" Then _
     rw.Cells(iRow, iClassification).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 9    ' Dark Red
End If
```

Comment: Now the error is on the:  ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Directory & sFN, FileFormat:=50 line (this extension can not be used with the selected file type).  Thank you :).

Comment: `FileFormat:=50 means` you want to save in binary format with an extension of `xlsb`.  But you have already specified the extension as `xlsx`.  You can have either but not both.

Comment: I changed it to ".xlsx" FileFormat:=50, but how do I save the file disabling the macros (macro-free)?  Thanks :).

Comment: Sorry, I use an old version of Excel that lacks these features so I cannot experiement.  I would drop the `FileFormat:=50`.  My understanding is that saving a workbook with an extension of `xlsx` deletes any macros.